# Dynamic style with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom-events

I want to to add and remove the style `pointer-events:none;` attribute dynamically with Vue.js:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  data: {
    toggled: false
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      this.toggled = !this.toggled;
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="el">
  <!-- The style disables all mouse events in the div -->
  <div style="pointer-events:none;">
    ...
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="toggle">Toggle click</button>
</div>
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#el',
    data: {
       toggled: false
    },
    methods: {
      toggle: function () {
        this.toggled = !this.toggled;
      },
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="el">
  <!-- The style disables all mouse events in the div -->
  <div :style="{ 'pointer-events': toggled ? 'none' : null }">
    ...
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="toggle">Toggle click</button>
</div>
```

Your `<button>` is outside the `#el`, causing it not to be parsed by the Vue.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot the button, but that's merely for the example, my code is not like that.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi okay, the answer is :style attribute, see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically change style on an HTML component, you can assign or remove a class to a given component based on a data value, for example:

```
<template>
   <div @click="toggleData=!toggleData">Click to toggle</div>
   <div :class="[toggleData ? 'classA' : 'classB']"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      toggleData: false,
    };
  },
</script>

<style>
.classA{
  pointer-events:none;
}
.classB{
    pointer-events:auto;
}
</style>
```

Comment: That's a really good answer, but I'd rather not use classes for such a simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed property that returns an object, where key represents the property and value represents the css property value.
Here is the example of using computed property -

```
<div id="el">
  <!-- The style disables all mouse events in the div -->
  <div v-bind:style="dynamicStyleObject">
  ...
  </div>
  <button v-on:click="toggle">Toggle click</button>
</div>


computed:{
    dynamicStyleObject:function(){
       // Conditionally return object in the following format -
       return {
          'pointer-events' : 'none',
          'some-other-property' : 'some-value'
       };
    }
}
```

Using computed property is much convenient because, whenever the data of the component changes, the dynamicStyleObject changes automatically and accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for something like this**

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <h1 v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }"> Text </h1>
      <button @click='condition = true'>Click me</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script> 
export default {
  data(){
   return {
   condition:false,
   activeColor: 'white',
   fontSize: 12
          }
         }
   }
</script>
```